# Is there a possibility of GPIO failure?

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I made my GPIO working as I want, but is there a possibility of GPIO failure after some time? My raspberry will work 24/7, GPIO pins will be used for like 20 minutes a day and I'm wondering if I should worry about it, since a failure where rasp would send signals when it shouldn't would be a disaster. I will take care of good envrimoment (no humiditiy etc).

Comment: What do you mean "would be a disaster"?  There are all sorts of regulations about the production of safety critical software and hardware.

Comment: A disaster might be a exaggeration, but it would be pretty bad. It cannot happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're not putting unnecessary strain on the pins, you should be ok. Just make sure that:

- All inputs use 3v3 logic
- All connecting cables are shorter than 1m (this is only sometimes a problem)
- Your power supply is sufficient
- All connections are sturdy and not going to fail/break

Other than that, you should be fine, keep in mind that NO computer runs forever.

Comment: Alright, great. What does 3v3 logic means? I know about computer running forever, I will make sure that it will work fine, and it's not a problem if it stops running, I'm more worried about raspberry sending signals to pins when it shouldnt.

Comment: @RokDolinar as long as your program doesn't tell it to send signals, it shouldn't. 3v3 logic means that [when using the pins for input]: HIGH is anywhere between 2v and 3.3v, and low is anywhere between .8v and 0v. This is different from some/most electronic boards that use 5v logic. Just make sure any input to the GPIO is below 3.6v as that is the absolute maximum the board can handle without immediate damage.

Comment: And if we move to a software part of my project.. If I'm programming in python should I handle GPIO exceptions, or do I skip it?

Comment: @RokDolinar Just want to make the point that I have had GPIO running 24/7 on my Pi 2 for almost 9 months now. It has been running both I2C and PWM that entire time, not once have I had it fail.

Comment: @RokDolinar the only time `RPi.GPIO` (assuming that's the package you're using) returns an exception or error is because of an incorrect initialization, which would be a one time piece of code at the beginning of your program, and once it's fixed, it should never return an error/exception.